# How can I fix this eslint errors: "Expected a newline after '('" and "Unexpected newline after '('"

Tags: eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have some code to define a shape of an immutable record using `typed-immutable` (Not relevant to this question. Just to provide a backdrop)

I apply the lint check based on `airbnb` rules and I get this error:
    `20:1  error  Line 20 exceeds the maximum line length of 80  max-len`

This is the offending line:

```
  type: new AnyOf(ITEM_A, ITEM_B, ITEM_C, ITEM_D, ITEM_E, ITEM_F, ITEM_G),
```

So naturally I break it into two lines:

```
  type: new AnyOf(ITEM_A, ITEM_B, ITEM_C, ITEM_D, ITEM_E, ITEM_F,
    ITEM_G),
```

Now a set of error messages is triggered:

```
  20:18  error  Expected a newline after '('   function-paren-newline
  21:19  error  Expected a newline before ')'  function-paren-newline
```

In order to appease the `lint` god, I tried the following format:

```
  type: new AnyOf(
    ITEM_A, ITEM_B, ITEM_C, ITEM_D, ITEM_E, ITEM_F, ITEM_G,
  ),
```

Now the error has become:

```
  20:18  error  Unexpected newline after '('   function-paren-newline
  22:3   error  Unexpected newline before ')'  function-paren-newline
```

It looks like airbnb disapproves every possible combination of formatting!

How can I fix it?

Comment: Seems like this resolve your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46871594/3332734

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/implicit-arrow-linebreak